# SQL Server Reporting Services: creating a Pareto chart

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to create a Pareto Chart in SQL Server Reporting Service 2005. I created a chart, but having difficulties in trying to get my cumulative(line) to display. I listed my values below.

**=SUM(Fields!Total_SR.Value)/MAX(Fields!Total_SR.Value,
"SeriesGroup")*0.75**

cumulative value:

**=RunningValue(Fields!Total_SR,
Sum, "SeriesGroup") / Sum(Fields!Total_SR, "SeriesGroup")**

I am able to get the Bar to display.

This is the instructions I used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I found the video by Michael J Swart really useful on creating pareto charts - 
http://michaeljswart.com/2008/10/reporting-services-is-fun-again%E2%80%A6/

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be something like the following (with the .Value)?:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Total_SR.Value, Sum, "SeriesGroup") / Sum(Fields!Total_SR.Value, "SeriesGroup")
```